# WP8 Item not found in LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollto, longlistselector

I am trying to scroll to a particular item in LongListSelector, but my longlistselector cannot find it and crashes when I call the llsTest.ScrollTo(m) function.

---

C#:

```C#
public class MyItem 
{
    public string s1 {get;set;}
    public string z1 {get;set;}

}

List<MyItem> list= new List<MyItem>();
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "First", z1 = "Second" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Third", z1 = "Fourth" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Fifth", z1 = "Sixth" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Sek8", z1 = "kj98" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "lkdsj9", z1 = "lkdjo0" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "jkdlhf", z1 = "98uifie" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Seventh11", z1 = "Eighth32" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Seventh45", z1 = "Eighth67" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Seventh86", z1 = "Eighth89" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Seventh6", z1 = "Eighth7" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Sevent4h", z1 = "Eighth8" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Seventh7i", z1 = "Eighthlp" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Seventh-09", z1 = "Eighth-0" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Seventh1q", z1 = "Eighthh65" });
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Second Last", z1 = "Last" });

MyItem m = new MyItem() { s1 = "Second Last", z1 = "Last" };

llsTest.ItemsSource = list;
llsTest.ScrollTo(m);  // **<========Crashes here, m cannot be found!**
```

---

Here is the XAML:

```XAML
<phone:LongListSelector Name="llsTest">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding s1}"/><LineBreak/>
                <Run Text="{Binding z1}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
 </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a new item to ScrollTo, give the item from the list array. I see from the code that you want to scroll to the 15th item. So write the code like below:

```
llsTest.ScrollTo(list[15]);
```

Comment: Well, I don't have the index information in advance.  I want to scroll to an item based on the contents of the item.  Is that a possibility?  I have tried the same thing with simple strings.  If the longlistselector is populated with simple strings, the scrollto works fine the way I have used it.  But when I use items based on a class, scrollto fails.  Any ideas?

Comment: In that case, loop through your list and find the index of the item based upon its content to which you want to scroll. And then pass the item index to scroll to as I have shown in my code

Answer (score 1):

`MyItem m = new MyItem() { s1 = "Second Last", z1 = "Last" };` now after this above line `m` is never added to list. so obviously it will throw an exception while trying to scroll to a non existing item.

> Note that, every call to `new` creates a new object, so even if the
>   content of objects are same, different objects would never be the
>   same.

so object passed in to

```
list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Second Last", z1 = "Last" });
```

isn't same as object created afterwards.

```
MyItem m = new MyItem() { s1 = "Second Last", z1 = "Last" };
```

u need to call `list.Add(m)` before call to `llsTest.ScrollTo(m);`

u can then remove a redundant element by removing line `list.Add(new MyItem() { s1 = "Second Last", z1 = "Last" });`

Comment: Ok, that explains things very well. Objects are not the same, even though the values are.  So in my case then, I want to scroll based on values contained in the object, not a specific instance of the object.  These values are stored somewhere else in isolatedstroage.  So I guess the solution presented by Hitesh would be acceptable although I will have to keep track of item number in my class so I can scrollto with an index to my list.